# TLS/SSL RABBIT MQ (Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host..)

Tags: c#, .net, security, ssl, rabbitmq

TLS/SSL following steps as:

To create the root CA certificate

1. genrsa -des3 -out CA-key.pem 2048
2. req -new -key CA-key.pem -x509 -days 1000 -out CA-cert.pem -subj "/C=US/ST=Oregon/L=Portland/O=user/OU=Org/CN=right.xcl.one"

To create a Signing a Server Certificate:

1. genrsa -des3 -out server-key.pem 2048
2. req –new –config openssl.cnf –key server-key.pem –out signingReq.csr
3. x509 -req -days 365 -in signingReq.csr -CA CA-cert.pem -CAkey CA-key.pem -CAcreateserial -out server-cert.pem

Client Certificate :-

1. pkcs12 -export -out client-cert.p12 -inkey server-key.pem -in server-cert.pem

Server RabbitMQ Config:-

```
[
{rabbit,  [ 
   {auth_mechanisms, ['EXTERNAL']},
   {loopback_users, []},
   {ssl_listeners, [5671]},
   {ssl_options, [{cacertfile,"D:/RabbitMQ/certs/CA-cert.pem"},
                 {certfile,"D:/RabbitMQ/certs/server-cert.pem"},
                 {keyfile,"D:/RabbitMQ/certs/server-key.pem"},
                 {verify,verify_peer}, 
                 {password,  "test"},
                {fail_if_no_peer_cert, false}]
               }         
]}
].
```

In C# Calling from local:-

```
var hostName = "right.xcl.one";
           var cf = new ConnectionFactory
           {
               HostName = hostName,
               UserName = "user",
               Password = "user",
               VirtualHost = "/",
               AuthMechanisms = new IAuthMechanismFactory[] { new ExternalMechanismFactory() },
               Ssl = new SslOption
               {
                   Enabled = true,
                   ServerName = "right.xcl.one",
                   AcceptablePolicyErrors = SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateNameMismatch |
                                           SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateChainErrors,
                   CertPath = @"D:\client-cert.p12",
                   CertPassphrase = "test",
                }
           };
           using (IConnection conn = cf.CreateConnection())
```

### OpenSSL> s_client -connect malta1597.startdedicated.com:5671 -cert client-cert.pem -key client-key.pem -CAfile CA-cert.pem -verify 8 -verify_hostname malta1597.startdedicated.com\ -state -debug
verify depth is 8
Enter pass phrase for client-key.pem:
CONNECTED(00000144)
SSL_connect:before SSL initialization
write to 0x1924d107020 [0x1924d1267b0] (330 bytes => 330 (0x14A))
0000 - 16 03 01 01 45 01 00 01-41 03 03 f7 84 a2 00 f6   ....E...A.......
0010 - 82 f2 f0 ef 26 79 3d fb-56 dd f9 37 79 fd 19 58   ....&y=.V..7y..X
0020 - 81 c8 a0 bc b3 5f f3 b5-29 a3 73 20 f8 06 9d 28   ....._..).s ...(
0030 - ec eb 1b c8 e6 f8 4f fe-97 1c 74 23 93 8f db ef   ......O...t#....
0040 - 8a ad 18 af 71 96 c2 40-b1 99 9d 92 00 3e 13 02   ....q..@.....>..
0050 - 13 03 13 01 c0 2c c0 30-00 9f cc a9 cc a8 cc aa   .....,.0........
0060 - c0 2b c0 2f 00 9e c0 24-c0 28 00 6b c0 23 c0 27   .+./...$.(.k.#.'
0070 - 00 67 c0 0a c0 14 00 39-c0 09 c0 13 00 33 00 9d   .g.....9.....3..
0080 - 00 9c 00 3d 00 3c 00 35-00 2f 00 ff 01 00 00 ba   ...=.<.5./......
0090 - 00 00 00 21 00 1f 00 00-1c 6d 61 6c 74 61 31 35   ...!.....malta15
00a0 - 39 37 2e 73 74 61 72 74-64 65 64 69 63 61 74 65   97.startdedicate
00b0 - 64 2e 63 6f 6d 00 0b 00-04 03 00 01 02 00 0a 00   d.com...........
00c0 - 0c 00 0a 00 1d 00 17 00-1e 00 19 00 18 00 23 00   ..............#.
00d0 - 00 00 16 00 00 00 17 00-00 00 0d 00 30 00 2e 04   ............0...
00e0 - 03 05 03 06 03 08 07 08-08 08 09 08 0a 08 0b 08   ................
00f0 - 04 08 05 08 06 04 01 05-01 06 01 03 03 02 03 03   ................
0100 - 01 02 01 03 02 02 02 04-02 05 02 06 02 00 2b 00   ..............+.
0110 - 09 08 03 04 03 03 03 02-03 01 00 2d 00 02 01 01   ...........-....
0120 - 00 33 00 26 00 24 00 1d-00 20 d3 71 9e 9a b6 7d   .3.&.$... .q...}
0130 - 1f 40 6c f3 35 dc b0 86-bc 52 c9 7e ba b8 64 0b   .@l.5....R.~..d.
0140 - d7 09 df b9 a5 34 15 f4-0f 1e                     .....4....
SSL_connect:SSLv3/TLS write client hello
read from 0x1924d107020 [0x1924d11d593] (5 bytes => -1 (0xFFFFFFFF))
SSL_connect:error in SSLv3/TLS write client hello
write:errno=10054

### no peer certificate available

### No client certificate CA names sent

### SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 330 bytes
Verification: OK

### New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)

read from 0x1924d107020 [0x1924d0fb0a0] (8192 bytes => -1 (0xFFFFFFFF))
error in s_client
OpenSSL>

**Authenticated successfully but the error is now:-**
One or more errors occurred. (Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host..)

Please help.

Comment: In the c# code where are you setting the port number 5671?

Comment: @jdweng 5671 is default port for ssl

Comment: Only Advanced Message Queuing Protocol (AMQP)[224] over TLS

Comment: @jdweng could you please let me know, what to do for AMQP

Comment: First see following : https://www.rabbitmq.com/build-dotnet-client.html  I will check source of library to see if I see what is causing issue.  Forcibly closed is an error coming from a TCP socket (SSL/TLS) where the socket connection fails.  It is caused by the endpoint.  c# will give this error is the client uses the loopback 127.0.0.1 or the connection parameters 1) Source IP 2) Designation IP 3) Port Number are being used.  A virus checker could be blocking the port number 5671.

Comment: See example : https://github.com/Azure/amqpnetlite/tree/master/Examples#listener-examples  Not sure which you are using.  But error is either due to "localhost" or loopback 127.0.0.1.  Problem often happens when client and server are on same machine.  localhost can be configured different on a machine so sometimes localhost will work on one machine and not another.